# cfvideoplayer javascript error in IE 7 & 8

Tags: coldfusion, colorbox, railo

I am using Railo CFVideoPlayer tag with colorbox effect in my project. It is working fine in all browsers except IE (Version 7 & 8).IE 9 is fine. I am getting below JS error line# 11 in /railo-context/swfobject.js.cfm & I am getting only loading symbol.

Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 11
Char: 3894
Code: 0
URI: http://Mysite/railo-context/swfobject.js.cfm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whats the version you using? Upgrade it to the latest and give it a try again!

Not to forget.. First Uninstall your Flash and then do a re-install.

For more on this topic read this lengthy comments driven page [here](http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2007/6/21/swfobject-problem-ie7)